# Are timestamps stored with a timezone in Apache Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

The following discussion seems to indicate that Hive timestamps have a timezone:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/83523/timestamp-in-hive-without-timezone.html

The apache wiki says "Timestamps are interpreted to be timezoneless and stored as an offset from the UNIX epoch."

I am referring to: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps

If I use code like the following:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(ts_field,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z') as ts_field_tz
```

This seems to expose an underlying timezone value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase *"timezone-less"* is misleading; what it means actually is that...

> If you have data files written by Hive, those `TIMESTAMP` values
>   represent the **local timezone** of the host where the data was **written**

That is an excerpt from the [Impala documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/impala_timestamp.html) -- and they make it very explicit, because it's a real pain when you need to access the same table from both Hive *and* Impala, since contrary to Hive...

> By default, Impala does not store timestamps using the local timezone,
>   to avoid undesired results from unexpected time zone issues.
>   Timestamps are stored and interpreted relative to UTC