# Getting Millisecond in Hive timestamp with offset Timezone

Tags: string, hadoop, hive, timestamp, utc

I want to convert a timestamp to millisecond with different formats in hive.

Currently I'm able to convert a string to the correct timestamp using the following code but wanted to store the timestamp data type from something of the format of  `YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS[.sss][Z | [ + | - hh[:mm]]]` where:

- YYYY = 0000 to 9999
- MM = 01-12
- DD = 01-31
- HH = 00-23 hours
- MM = 00-59 minutes
- SS = 00-59 seconds
- sss = milliseconds
- hh = 01-12 offset hours
- mm = 00-59 offset minutes

Example: `20060901-02:39-05` is five hours behind UTC, thus Eastern Time on 1st of September 2006 and the timestamp with be in the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` format

What I have for UTC timestamp of `YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.sss` is as follows:

```
cast(concat(concat_ws('-',substr(tag[52],1,4), substr(tag[52],5,2), substr(tag[52],7,2)),
     space(1),
     concat_ws(':',substr(tag[52],10,2), substr(tag[52],13,2), substr(tag[52],16,2)),
     '.', substr(tag[52],19,3)) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

This takes a tag and does string manipulation of values of the tag to put into Timestamp datatype resulting in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.sss`...

I would like something similar to this that puts into Timestamp **with offset** in Hive.

Is this even possible?

Comment: My 2 cents: convert your bizarre timestamp strings into a "UNIX time" _(long integer, number of ms since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)_ then **display** that absolute date/time with whatever format you want in whatever circumstances you need to display it.

Comment: Read the documentation about "Date functions" at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions >> `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime`, `from_utc_timestamp` and `to_utc_timestamp`, `date_format` etc.

Comment: BTW you might be interested about the way Hive manages *implicitly* time zones with its `TimeStamp` "native" data type... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647134/are-timestamps-stored-with-a-timezone-in-apache-hive/

Comment: Problem is I need the milliseconds of a custom timestamp of the format YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.sss and the unix_timestamp function in hive drops the milliseconds.

Comment: Good point. Still, you could get the "rounded" TS and add the milliseconds extracted separately via `cast(regexp_extract(...) as int)`